# Using parse to query info in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I am currently trying to implement a parse database into a Swift app. I am having trouble understanding how to use the data, when you query from parse. Here is a query I am using:

```
    var query = PFQuery(className: "CompanyInfo")

    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({
        (objects: [AnyObject]! , error: NSError!) -> Void in

        if error == nil{
            println("Successfully retrieved \(objects.count) specials.")
            println(objects[0])
        }else{
            println(error)
        }
    })
```

So I know this works because it prints out all the data to the console.

Then when I do the `objects[0]` it prints out the first.

How would I use the objects to set data into my app? For instance, if I have a title section in my parse class `CompanyInfo`, how do I get that information for later on?

Comment: var object = objects[0] as PFObject & get title like this - object["title"] as? String

Comment: Can I make that into an array and then return that to a different function?

Comment: @user081608 It already is an array.

Comment: Okay so I can just return objects?

Comment: Its already an array so take NSMutableArray, do mutableCopy of objects then you can use anywhere in your class :)

Comment: Thank you. When I do object["Title"] I get it as type AnyObject. How would I set that to a string?

Comment: object["Title"] as String

Answer (score 0):

To get the objects as PFObjects just cast them..

```
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({
    (objects: [AnyObject]! , error: NSError!) -> Void in
        var myPFObjects = objects as? [PFObject] // now you have your array of pfobjects
})
```

To get any attribute/column of a pfobject just call it like this

```
var aPFObject = myPFObjects[0]
var title = aPFObject["title"] as? String
```

A better way to do all these things is to subclass the pfobject and get them via class properties, which would make following code:

The subclass..

```
class CompanyInfo: PFObject, PFSubclassing {

    var title: String? {
        get {
            return self["title"] as? String
        }
        set {
            self["title"] = newValue
        }
    }


    class func parseClassName() -> String! {
        return "CompanyInfo"
    }
}
```

and the code where you call the query:

```
var cpQuery = CompanyInfo.query()
cp.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({
    (objects: [AnyObject]! , error: NSError!) -> Void in
    var myCompanyInfos = objects as? [CompanyInfo] //Directly cast them to your objects
    for cp in myCompanyInfos {
        println(cp.title) //print all the titles
    }
})
```